# Calling member function from another class

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create a Blackjack simulator. I need to shuffle the deck before dealing cards to both the player and the dealer. `shuffleDeck` is a void function and `dealCard` is of type Card within class `Deck`. Class `Card` stores the cards that are dealt from the class `Deck`. At the very beginning of the game, I need to deal two cards to both the player and the dealer.
When I tried to access the member function of `Deck` in class `Game`, I got the error message "Call to non-static member function without an object argument". What is the correct way for calling member functions? I'm really confused by the syntax.

```
void Game::deal()
{
    // shuffle deck
    // deal two cards to the player and two to the dealer
    Deck::shuffleDeck();
    Player::acceptCard (Deck::dealCard());
}
```

Comment: First of all you need instances of `Deck` and `Player`, I'd suspect best as member variables of `Game`.

Comment: You're confusing classes with objects. We usually recommend [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the the class `Deck` not an instance of `Deck`! 
(I suppose your `Deck` class isn't desinged as a singelton. It should not be a singelton!).

I guess you want to have a member of type `Deck` in your class `Game`:

```
class Game:
{
...
private:
 Deck my_deck;
}
```

which you can use in your deal method

```
void Game::deal()
{
    ...
    myDeck.shuffleDeck();
    ...
}
```